# Maximum dimensions of Mobile Safari viewport on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I need to know the maximum width and height of the viewport in Mobile Safari, iPhone 4, without the height of the statusbar on top and the bar with the forward/back/bookmarks bar at the bottom.

Comment: Do you mean the maximum values of the `viewport` meta property? If so, you probably should have posted this on [so] since it is development related. And the answer is 10000x10000 ([see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW7)).

Comment: Check my answer to similar question on SO, might help a little - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205812/jquery-js-ios-4-and-document-height-problems

Answer (score 6):

The iPhone 4 display is 320 by 480 points in size total.  The status bar is 20 points high, and the tool bar at the bottom in 44 points high.

Comment: According to the official specs, the Iphone 4 has a resolution of 960x640. So that can't be it...

Comment: There are 2 hardware pixels per point on an iPhone 4 (scale = 2.0).  1 hardware pixel per point on a 3GS (scale = 1.0).  But Javascript and css px maps to points, not hardware pixels.